# Cannot Establish Distributed Tsung Load Test: Can't start newbeam on host remote_test (reason: timeout)

Tags: tsung

I'm trying to establish distributed Tsung load test, But without luck, it failed anyway.

Background:
Two virtual machines in a same network,the name of 192.168.14.145 in /etc/hosts is "master"and the name of 192.168.14.146 is "remote_test"; 
Same Tsung version(Tsung 1.6.0), same Erlang version(OTP 18.0); 
Each virtural machine has access to another through ssh;

Trials:
According to http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/faq.html#can-t-start-distributed-clients-timeout-error I can confirm:

- SSH is working
- Tsung and Erlang are installed on all nodes and with the same version
- A firewall is not dropping Erlang packets (service iptables stopped)
- SELinux Disabled, status is Permissive
- Bad /etc/hosts...........Nope, 
  on 192.168.14.145: 
  master 192.168.14.145 
  remote_test 192.168.14.146
  on 192.168.14.146:
  master 192.168.14.145
- sshd configuration............Run "ssh remote_test erl", Erlang shell started;

Notes:
If I point the name "remote_test" to 192.168.14.145, everything went smoothly.

Comment: Well, somehow now it worked. I did nothing more than try again.

Comment: Now I'm trying to reappear the issue again.